# Как правильно построить структуру БД на Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Нужно создать страницу контактов (с управлением из админки) в которой
1. Будет форма для отправки сообщений с дропдауном из емайл адресов.
2. Будет список контактов разделенный на отделы компании такого формата
-> (к примеру) | Приемная (номер, номер, емайл), Отдел кадров (номер, емайл), бухгалтерия (номер, номер, номер).
Данные могут меняться, к примеру в приемной (номер, емайл, емайл).
3. Табы районов одного города в которой так же несколько значений
-> (к примеру). Центр города (Отдел1-(номер, номер), отдел2-(номер), Отдел3-(номер, номер, номер)).
Номера в 3-м пункте не повторяются , и не связаны с данными из пункта но. 2.
Как бы вы решили данную задачу? Спасибо за идеи заранее.

Comment: Как вариант, `ENUM` под `Приемная`, `Отдел кадров` и т. д.; поле под `# отдела`; два поля для почты и телефона, куда сохранять `json` (т. к. телефонов может быть много, не плодить же под каждый номер `phone_4`, `phone_5`, ...)

Comment: Хорошо, то бишь мне нужно 3 таблицы в бд для каждой из подзадач. А если еще добавить тот факт что для каждой из таблиц должны быть еще несколько языков то в итоге получается 6 таблиц. Как то хотелось бы уменьшить количество таблиц. Может есть какой нибудь другой вариант !? В любом случае спасибо за помощь !

Comment: почему 3 таблицы? Можно для других якзыков сделать доп. колонки в этой же. Возьмите `MySQL Workbench` да поиграйтесь